# facing this in my about page in django templates if i remove my css then it works well otherwise it gives me an error whenever i use to display images

Tags: python, django, templates

I am facing this problem  in my about page in django templates if i remove my css then it works well otherwise it gives me an error whenever i use to display images please reply as soon as possible please reply fast for this question if anyone can

```
Django Version: 3.0.5
Python Version: 3.7.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mysiteapp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rishabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Rishabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Rishabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\newproject\mysite\mysiteapp\views.py", line 27, in about
    return render(request,'about.html')
  File "C:\Users\Rishabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Rishabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Rishabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 15, in get_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\Rishabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "C:\Users\Rishabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\Rishabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "C:\Users\Rishabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 24, in get_template
    contents = self.get_contents(origin)
  File "C:\Users\Rishabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\filesystem.py", line 24, in get_contents
    return fp.read()
  File "C:\Users\Rishabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /about
Exception Value: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 1394: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Can you add the code of tempalte/view where you are seeing this error?

Comment: actually my template is running well only when i insert css in my html template then it not display any images and css and throw the same error

Comment: You may have incorrectly formatted CSS or django template tags/variables. Show your template and css code and we will be able to point out the error.